# Activar y desactivar BackGroundImage de un botón en VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net

Muy buen dia, tengo una duda, como puedo activar y desactivar el fondo que le he agragado desde la propiedad  *BackGroundImage* a un boton

Cuando se mantiene presionado se desactiva el fondo y se cambia de color

```
Private Sub Command3_Click() Handles Button3.MouseDown
    Button3.BackColor = Color.DarkGoldenrod
    Button3.BackgroundImage = Nothing

End Sub
```

Ahora deseo que al dejar de presionar se vuelva a activar la imagen de fondo

```
Private Sub Command3_Click2() Handles Button3.MouseUp
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme

Comment: Donde tienes la imagen cuando se carga el boton? la tienes en resources?

Comment: La he agregado desde la propiedad del botón, backgroundImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba asi:

```
Private Sub Command3_Click2() Handles Button3.MouseUp
 Button3.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.MyPicture
End Sub
```

MyPicture es la imagen